# SSRS: How To Create Dynamic Report With Multiple Subreports?

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, navision

I am still fairly new to SSRS, and I do not know what I need to/can provide as examples to help clarify my issue.

I am developing an SSRS report that accesses a NAV database and generates a report for an equipment number. My task is to generate a master report that can print multiple of those kind of reports(currently 10 max). I am using sub-reports to get the content that I need for an equipment number.

I am looking for a way to make this dynamic, where I can generate 1 to n sub-reports based on how many values were picked for the multi-value parameter. The end result should be one PDF file that contains the full report for each equipment number listed. I am trying to only use SSRS.

I have seen where I could hide sub-reports then make them visible if a condition is met, but this isn't the functionality that I am looking to use. So, what would be the best way to dynamically generate sub-reports based on a multi-value parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I made the sub-report parameter equal no value. I made the main report with a parameter that can select multiple equipment numbers, a list, and a data set which filtered down to the appropriate equipment numbers to avoid duplication. I made the sub-report object in the main take in the cell value from the list equipment number. When the list proceeded to the next row, it copied all of the objects in the box area.

Comment: Also in case my description is too brief, here is an example link that I found to get started. http://oakdome.com/programming/SSRS_UsingSubReports.php